# What are the proper pdf controls to integrate with .net application?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, pdf, telerik

I upload files in `pdf` format in my system . These files pass through many states and in every state the users write notes and dates and sign on them .

---

Now i use [RadPDF](http://www.radpdf.com/) to perform what i need , but it's not customizable enough and i feel it's limited . I want any recommendation to controls ,i can use in my asp.net application . so i can open my pdf file through it then write ,sign and save it .

I want to integrate it wiz my application like this :
[image]

Answer (score 6):

You need to evaluate a number of controls to best see what meets your requirements

http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/PDF/

Is just one example of a controls developed for developers with solid controls

Comment: Could u help me wiz some tutorial or explanation for using `Studio for ASP.NET Wijmo` ?

Answer (score 3):

I can also recommend [Component One](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/PDF/) as a good supplier, although I've not tried their PDF document editor, their other third party controls are in my opinion very good. Here are some of the other options I've looked at in the past:

http://www.bluebeam.com/

http://www.activepdf.com/products/serverproducts/toolkit/

http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/pdfnet/home

http://itextpdf.com/ (Open Source option which has a reasonable [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23105/Programmatically-Complete-PDF-Form-Fields-using-Vi))

Each have their own benefits and pitfalls so the decision ultimately lies with you comparing each (including cost of course) to determine the best option for you at this time.